# how perform kmean clustering divided by group variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
mydat=structure(list(x1 = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("-1.92624230", "-2.57056193", "-3.09681744", 
"-3.28609828", "-3.50194468", "-3.55091497", "-3.74673944", "-3.86974559", 
"-3.89210250", "-4.25903476"), class = "factor"), x2 = structure(c(3L, 
6L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("-0.68825893", 
"-1.07590781", "-1.37899638", "-1.77529942", "-1.82686130", "-2.00209107", 
"-2.26674165", "-2.45820610", "-3.02997384", "0.79498032"), class = "factor"), 
    glav = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), y = c(4195L, 
    4493L, 4386L, 4743L, 5348L, 5297L, 5353L, 3438L, 4024L, 2850L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

How can i perform `kmean` cluster analysis divided by group `glav`?
For each group 1 and 2, i must perform `kmean` clustering separately. I can do only for 1 group, but indeed i must perform it for multiple group separately.
But in cluster analysis `y` variable shouldn't take a part.
So how perform kmean for each group of `glav` with asigning of cluster number , i.e desired output

```
   x1            x2    glav y   clust
-3.50194468 -1.37899638 2   4195    1
-3.55091497 -2.00209107 2   4493    1
-3.28609828 -1.77529942 2   4386    2
-3.74673944 -1.07590781 2   4743    2
-3.86974559 -2.45820610 2   5348    1
-3.89210250 -3.02997384 1   5297    1
-4.25903476 -2.26674165 1   5353    1
-1.92624230 0.79498032  1   3438    1
-3.09681744 -1.82686130 1   4024    2
-2.57056193 -0.68825893 1   2850    2
```

Comment: What have you tried? First, you've tagged [tag:dplyr] and [tag:tidyr] which suggests you already have a flow before this need. Second, what call to `kmeans` makes sense for this data? How many clusters? I'm afraid that 5 data points is not going to be very useful for `kmeans` in practice here, so I suggest that a better alternative would be to work on a much larger public dataset (e.g., `iris`, `ggplot2::diamonds`, or `nycflights`), or to produce random data. (BTW: I'd think `by(mydat, mydat$glav, FUN=function(z) {do_kmeans_here(z);})` might be a reasonable start.)

Comment: Something like `results <- lappy(split(mydat, mydat$glav) function(x) kmeans(x[, c("x1", "x2")], centers=?))` will return a list with the kmeans results for each value of `glav`. You have to replace ? with the number of clusters you want.